# try multiple catch

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

Here's my code:

```
error_reporting(0);

$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost",'root','','alex');
try{
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        throw new Exception("Database error!");
    }else{
        $query=$mysqli->query("Select companie,sum(suma) as suma from muncitori group by companie");
        if(!$query){
            throw new LastException("Query failed!");
        }
    }
    while($result=$query->fetch_array()){
        echo "Compania $result[companie] a cheltuit suma $result[suma] lei<br>";
    }
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}catch (LastException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
class LastException extends Exception{}
```

If my query failed and i throw the exception, the (LastException $s) catch block doesn't catch the exception but the (Exception $e) catch it. Where is the problem? Why Exception catch exception  insteed of LastException?

Comment: Please, rephrase your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reorder catch-blocks: from the most *specific* to the most *general*, e.g.:

```
try {
   //...
} catch (LastException $e) {
   //...
} catch (Exception $e) {
   //...
}
```

Things to know:

- catch-blocks are processed sequentially: from top to bottom;
- the first matching catch-block will be executed;

So if you place `} catch (Exception $e)` first,then it will catch all exceptions as `Exception` is base class for all exceptions in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse those 2 exceptions:

```
} catch (LastException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $s) {
    echo $s->getMessage();
}
```